# Why is it throwing an error even after migrations?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a website for an online store, and after creating and registering models, I don't know why, this error is thrown. What can I do? And also after running the migrate command, it is saying no migrations to apply. How can I do this?

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in


stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class UserStripe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.stripe_id)


def get_or_create_stripe(sender, user, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user.userstripe.stripe_id
    except UserStripe.DoesNotExist:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email = str(user.email)
        )
        new_user_stripe = UserStripe.objects.create(
            user  = user,
            stripe_id = customer.id
            )
    except:
        pass

user_logged_in.connect(get_or_create_stripe)
```

Comment: What error is it throwing?  Did you run the "makemigrations" command?  (If you didn't then there won't be a migration for the "migrate" command to run.)

Comment: Yes I did run both commands

Comment: Did "makemigrations" make a migration?  Can you see the .py file it created?  Does it contain the right stuff?  And the answer to my first question?