# Why is it throwing an error even after migrations? (no such table: accounts_userstripe)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a website for an online store, and after creating and registering models, I don't know why, this error is thrown. What can I do? And also after running the migrate command, it is saying no migrations to apply. How can I do this?

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class UserStripe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.stripe_id)


def get_or_create_stripe(sender, user, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user.userstripe.stripe_id
    except UserStripe.DoesNotExist:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email = str(user.email)
        )
        new_user_stripe = UserStripe.objects.create(
            user  = user,
            stripe_id = customer.id
            )
    except:
        pass

user_logged_in.connect(get_or_create_stripe)
```

Comment: Could you provide a full text of the error?

Comment: OperationalError at /admin/accounts/userstripe/
no such table: accounts_userstripe

Comment: Another time-wasting self-duplicate, asked two hours after the original: [Why is it throwing an error even after migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028297/why-is-it-throwing-an-error-even-after-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed anything since your last migration ?
I think you might have changed some models, now django is unable to find your table.

I would delete the current migration files and create new ones.

Comment: this could have been a comment.

Comment: I have deleted the migrations and created new ones, but it says the same: Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

Comment: I never used stripe before but when I read there documentation I see options for accounts. Might be this is where your error originates from. Did you have a look at : "https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create" ? Maybe try to create an account and run it again to see if this still throws the error.